# Pinging server with payload from tclsh

Tags: windows, tcl, ping

I need to test how my remote server is handling ping request. I need to ping remote server from my windows with payload of say 50 kb. I need my tcl script sholud generate 20 such ping requests with 50 kb payload parallel so it will result 1 mb receive traffic at server at given instance. here is the code for ping test

```
proc ping-igp {} {
    foreach i {
        172.35.122.18
    } {
        if {[catch {exec ping $i -n 1 -l 10000} result]} {
            set result 0
        }
        if {[regexp "Reply from $i"  $result]} {
            puts "$i pinged"
        } else {
            puts "$i Failed"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: @Luke I'm looking for tcl script which will ping remote server with more than 20 ping request same time without opening another tclsh.exe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ping in parallel then you can use `open` instead of exec and use fileevents to read from the ping process.

An example of using open to ping a server with two parallel processes:

```
set server 172.35.122.18

proc pingResult {chan serv i} {
    set reply [read $chan]
    if {[eof $chan]} {
        close $chan
    }
    if {[regexp "Reply from $serv"  $result]} {
        puts "$serv number $i pinged"
    } else {
        puts "$serv number $i Failed"
    }
}

for {set x 0} {$x < 2} {incr $x} {
    set chan [open "|ping $server -n 1 -l 10000"]
    fileevent $chan readable "pingResult $chan {$server} $x"
}
```

See this page for more info: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl26.html

Comment: Thanks @slebetman can you please give more information how code is flowing after list apply as I'm not understanding the code.One more thing while executing this code I get trail error,,,
#couldn't execute "ping": not enough memory
#ping
unable to alloc 1344 bytes
#this application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: apply is just a function to treat a specially formatted string as a function and execute it immediately without needing to define the function. If you're confused by this then simply use a regular function. I'll edit the code to make what I'm doing more obvious. As for list, it's just a form of quoting, just like "" and {} only that it generates a proper list from its arguments whereas string operations may produce an invalid list

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple piece of code to do the pinging in the background by opening a pipeline. To do that, make the first character of the “filename” to `open` be a `|`, when the rest of the “filename” is interpreted as a Tcl list of command line arguments, just as in `exec`:

```
proc doPing {host} {
    # These are the right sort of arguments to ping for OSX.
    set f [open "|ping -c 1 -t 5 $host"]
    fconfigure $f -blocking 0
    fileevent $f readable "doRead $host $f"
}

proc doRead {host f} {
    global replies
    if {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
        if {[regexp "Reply from $host" $result]} {
            # Switch to drain mode so this pipe will get cleaned up
            fileevent $f readable "doDrain $f"
            lappend replies($host) 1
            incr replies(*)
        }
    } elseif {[eof $f]} {
        # Pipe closed, search term not present
        lappend replies($host) 0
        incr replies(*)
        close $f
    }
}

# Just reads and forgets lines until EOF
proc doDrain {f} {
    gets $f
    if {[eof $f]} {close $f}
}
```

You'll also need to run the event loop; this might be trivial (you're using Tk) or might need to be explicit (`vwait`) but can't be integrated into the above. But you can use a clever trick to run the event loop for long enough to collect all the results:

```
set hosts 172.35.122.18
set replies(*)
foreach host $hosts {
    for {set i 0} {$i < 20} {incr i} {
        doPing $host
        incr expectedCount
    }
}
while {$replies(*) < $expectedCount} {
    vwait replies(*)
}
```

Then, just look at the contents of the `replies` array to get a summary of what happened.